# Disable Access to files with express node server

Tags: node.js, apache, express

I have a node server running on CentOS and currently, you can just go to any file in the root and view it, for example `xxx.net/whatever.js`. This is obviously not great, as i have some sensitive information in certain files.

**How can i disable users from navigating to these files from a browser?**

I have an apache proxy set up to view the site like so

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin me@xxx.net
  ServerName www.xxx.net
  ServerAlias xxx.net

  DocumentRoot /var/www/xxx.net
  <Directory /var/www/xxx.net>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
  </Directory>

  ErrorLog /var/www/xxx.net/error.log
  CustomLog /var/www/xxx.net/requests.log combined

  ProxyRequests Off
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyVia Full
  <Proxy *>
   Require all granted
  </Proxy>

  <Location />
    ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:4000/
    ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:4000/
  </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

and then pm2 running an express node server. I've tried all sorts of chmod'ing but nothing has changed. If anybody could shed any light onto my problem that would be great. If you need any more info let me know, thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can restrict the access using express js.

when this is written

```
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname));
```

this means access anything

you can limit this access to some folders only using

```
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Or you can write middleware in express that can have the list of file routes you want to block

```
    app.use(function (req, res, next) {
        if(!checkFunction(req.url)) {
            next();
        } else {
            res.send(404, "Not found");
        }
    })

    var checkFunction(url){
       var blockedUrl = ['folder/file1.js'];

       return blockedUrl.find(function(urlCheck){
            return urlCheck === url;
       })
    }
```

Comment: I definitely have used the public folder version before... this time i was planning on just generating the site as html but last minute decided to leave it dynamic... so i didn't use the pub. But i'll definitely try the `checkFunction` technique! thanks a lot for the examples.